# How to solve this ODE $(1-2xy)y'=y(y-1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It appears in the section of first-order linear equations, and may only need a variable substitution, but I tried many and couldn’t get the desired result. Can anyone help me ? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: I can't transfer it into the form of $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$. I try to let $\frac{1}{y}=z$ or $1-2xy=z$,  but this cannot get the desired form.@Surb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation for $x$ as a function of $y$ is linear:
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{y'}=\frac{1-2xy}{y(y-1)}\Rightarrow\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{2}{y-1}x=\frac{1}{y(y-1)}.
$$

Comment: Good idea.  Instead of $y$ as a function of $x$, a non-linear DE, think of $x$ as a function of $y$ to get a linear DE.

Answer (score 1):

Linear with
$$\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{2x}{y-1}=\frac1{y(y-1))}$$

which can be solved as it is in the form of $\frac{dx}{dy}+p(y)x=q(y)...$

or you can use exact differentials as
$$dy-2xydy-y^2dx+ydx=0$$ and then this can be rearranged by dividing by $y$ and proceeding

$$dx+ 2yxdy+y^2dx-dy-2dyx-2ydx+\frac{dy}y=0$$

.. which is an exact form of

$$dx+d(y^2x)-dy-d(2xy)+d(\log y)=0$$

which on integrating gives us

$$x(y-1)^2-y+\log y=C$$ where $C$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

##### Transform

You can rewrite the ODE a bit with $\frac{1}{y'} = \frac{1}{\frac{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x}} = \frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y\left( x \right)} = \frac{\operatorname{d}x\left( y \right)}{\operatorname{d}y}$. You'll also sometimes see it under the transformation $y' = \frac{1}{x'} \wedge x' = \frac{1}{y'}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( 1 - 2 \cdot x \cdot y \right) \cdot y' &= y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right) \quad\mid\quad \div\left( y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right) \right)\\
\frac{1 - 2 \cdot x \cdot y}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} \cdot y' &= 1 \quad\mid\quad \div\left( y' \right)\\
\frac{1 - 2 \cdot x \cdot y}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \frac{1}{y'}\\
\frac{1 - 2 \cdot x \cdot y}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= x'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} + \frac{-2 \cdot x \cdot y}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= x'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} - \frac{2 \cdot y}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} \cdot x &= x'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} - \frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot x &= x'\\
\end{align*}
$$

You have now converted the intiger-order nonlinear ODE into a linear ODE.

##### Solving for $x$

###### Solving for $x_{h}$

From now on you can simply use the known methods, such as the substitution $x = e^{\lambda \cdot y}$ or simply solving, with which you can solve the homogeneous part of the solution $x_{h}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot x &= x_{h}' \quad\mid\quad \div x\\
-\frac{2}{y - 1} &= \frac{x'}{x} \quad\mid\quad \int\,\operatorname{d}y\\
-2 \cdot \ln\left( y - 1 \right) &= \ln\left( x_{h} \right)\\
\ln\left( \left( y - 1 \right)^{-2} \right) &= \ln\left( x_{h} \right) \quad\mid\quad \exp\left( \cdot \right)\\
\left( y - 1 \right)^{-2} &= x_{h}\\
\frac{1}{\left( y - 1 \right)^{2}} &= x_{h}\\
\end{align*}
$$

###### Solving for $x_{p}$

You can also substitute $x = v \cdot u \implies x' = v' \cdot u + v \cdot u'$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} - \frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot x &= x' \quad\mid\quad +\left( \frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot x \right)\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot x + x'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot u \cdot v + v' \cdot u + v \cdot u'\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot u \cdot v + v' \cdot u + v \cdot u'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \left( \underbrace{\frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot v + v'}_{=~ 0} \right) \cdot u + v \cdot u' \quad\mid\quad\div v\\
\frac{2}{y - 1} + \frac{v'}{v} &= 0 \quad\mid\quad \int\,\operatorname{d}y\\
2 \cdot \ln\left( y - 1 \right) + \ln\left( v \right) &= 0 \quad\mid\quad -2 \cdot \ln\left( y - 1 \right)\\
\ln\left( v \right) &= -2 \cdot \ln\left( y - 1 \right)\\
\ln\left( v \right) &= \ln\left( \left( y - 1 \right)^{-2} \right) \quad\mid\quad \exp\left( \cdot \right)\\
v &= \left( y - 1 \right)^{-2}\\
v &= \frac{1}{\left( y - 1 \right)^{2}}\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot u \cdot v + v' \cdot u + v \cdot u'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \left( \underbrace{\frac{2}{y - 1} \cdot v + v'}_{=~ 0} \right) \cdot u + v \cdot u'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= 0 \cdot u + v \cdot u'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= v \cdot u'\\
\frac{1}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= \frac{1}{\left( y - 1 \right)^{2}} \cdot u' \quad\mid\quad \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)^{2}\\
\frac{\left( y - 1 \right)^{2}}{y \cdot \left( y - 1 \right)} &= u'\\
\frac{y - 1}{y} &= u' \quad\mid\quad \int\,\operatorname{d}y\\
-\ln\left( y \right) + y &= u\\
\end{align*}
$$

##### Solution $x\left( y \right)$

So we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{c}{\left( y - 1 \right)^{2}} + \frac{-\ln\left( y \right) + y}{\left( y - 1 \right)^{2}}\\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
x\left( y \right) &= \frac{c - \ln\left( y \right) + y}{\left( y - 1 \right)^{2}}\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

A Plot of $y\left( x \right)$ where ${\color{Orange}{c = 2}}$, ${\color{Purple}{c = 1}}$, ${\color{Black}{c = 0}}$, ${\color{Red}{c = -1}}$, ${\color{Blue}{c = -2}}$ and ${\color{Green}{c = -3}}$:

[image]